# fluent security unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, authentication, authorization, fluent-security

I have been writing some tests on my Fluent Security configuration off late. Though I can write tests verifying if a controller action method has a particular policy applied e.g.

```
expectations.Expect<HomeController>(x=>x.Index()).Has<IgnorePolicy>();
```

However, what I am looking for is, if I can write role specific tests.

e.g If I have given Admin Role access only to Index() of HomeController, I want to test something like

```
expectations.Expect<HomeController>(x=>x.Index()).Has<RequireRolePolicy>().For("Admin");
```

I do not find any examples on net, or any extensions in FLuentSecurity.TestHelper that can help me do this. any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Has extension has an overload that takes a predicate:

```
expectations.Expect<HomeController>(x => x.Index())
    .Has<RequireRolePolicy>(policy => policy.RolesRequired.Contains("Admin"));
```

As you can see the RequireRolePolicy exposes a RolesRequired property that you can test against.

If you find yourself doing a lot of checking for a particular set of roles I would recommend creating a custom policy and just check for that policy instead. There's an example of this (an AdministratorPolicy) in the sample application on github: https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/blob/master/FluentSecurity.SampleApplication/AdministratorPolicy.cs

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please don't forget to accept this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Though I got this working but found a severe limitation to Fluent Security.
It is not able to differentiate between the two action methods with same name !!

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id){}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeCommand command){}
```

if I want to give access to Guest on Edit (Get) and Edit (Post) to Admin User, I cannot do it via Fluent Security as it identifies both the methods as one. I will not recommend this library as this is a severe limitation!

Comment: I am sorry that you find FluentSecurity lacking in some areas but this answer has nothing to do with your original question. Please delete this answer!

As for the feature you are missing, we are working on improvements all the time and if you post an issue on github we will do our best to support your request.